# Function to update input xml by passing instance of object using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I am new to JAXB, and am trying to write a function which takes input XML as string and a corresponding dynamic object which would be the top level wrapper object and may contain instances of some other classes defined by user.

I have created the function for this, and I am getting the inputXML as is in the output when there are no other objects of user defined classes in the class. When there is other user defined class in the object, then I am getting ClassCastException, as the user defined object is not getting casted

Will it be possible to achieve this, or if there is any other better method for this

Below are the classes I have created. Whenever I add the address object into the code, I get the ClassCastException, however when I comment out the code related to address field, then I am getting the inputXML as is in the output

Person.Java

```
package com.updater;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
@XmlType(propOrder={"firstName", "lastName", "phone", "address"})
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
    private Address address;

    @XmlElement(name="FirstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="LastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Phone")
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }


    @XmlElement(name="Address")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }   

}
```

Address.java

```
package com.updater;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
@XmlType(propOrder={"type", "line1", "city", "country", "zip"})
public class Address {

    private String type;
    private String line1;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String zip;

    @XmlElement(name="Type")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Line1")
    public String getLine1() {
        return line1;
    }
    public void setLine1(String line1) {
        this.line1 = line1;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="City")
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Country")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Zip")
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }
    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

}
```

JAXBUpdater.java

```
package com.updater;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.Binder;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class JAXBUpdater {

    public String updateXML(String inputXML, Object object) throws Exception {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(inputXML.getBytes());
        Document document = docBuilder.parse(bais);

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass());

        Binder<Node> binder=jaxbContext.createBinder();

        binder.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Node node=document.getDocumentElement();

        Object updObj=object.getClass().cast(binder.updateJAXB(node));

        node=binder.updateXML(object.getClass().cast(updObj));

        document.setNodeValue(node.getNodeValue());

        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(updObj, baos);
        return baos.toString();
    }
}
```

TestUpdate.java

```
package com.updater;

public class TestUpdate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       

        String inputXML="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>" +
        "<Person>" +
        "    <FirstName>AAAA</FirstName>" +
        "    <LastName>BBBB</LastName>" +
        "    <Phone>12345</Phone>" +
        "    <Address>" +
        "        <Type>Home</Type>" +
        "        <Line1>Line1</Line1>" +
        "        <City>CCCC</City>" +
        "        <Country>US</Country>" +
        "        <Zip>6666</Zip>" +
        "    </Address>" +
        "</Person>";

        //update fields using the objects of class
        Person person=new Person();
        person.setFirstName("XXXX");
        person.setLastName("YYYY");     
        person.setPhone("56789");


        Address address=new Address();
        address.setCity("ZZZZ");
        person.setAddress(address);


        JAXBUpdater updater=new JAXBUpdater();
        String outputXML=updater.updateXML(inputXML, person);

        System.out.println(outputXML);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which `ClassCastException`?

Comment: getting the exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.updater.Address to com.updater.Person